# How to eliminate duplicate code

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following methods, that all return different types. I have four of such methods.
In the spirit of good programming practices(DRY), should be using some OOP techniques such as inheritance or interfaces here or just roll with it. Any comments or code examples are welcome. Thank you.

```
  static AttendeeResponse GetAttendees(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AttendeeResponse));
            return (AttendeeResponse)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            error =  e.InnerException.ToString();
            return null;
        }

    }

    static MemberResponse GetMembers(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MemberResponse));
            return (MemberResponse)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = e.InnerException.ToString();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
// TODO: Improve the name :)
static T FetchItem<T>(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = e.InnerException.ToString();
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've included a `using` statment to avoid you leaking connections. You don't need to close the stream as well, according to the docs.

The `return null` had to change to `return default(T)` in case `T` is a non-nullable value type; an alternative would be to restrict `T` to be a reference type using `where T : class` as part of the method declaration.

Use it like this:

```
MemberResponse members = FetchItem<MemberResponse>(request);
...
AttendeeResponse attendee = FetchItem<AttendeeResponse>(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generics?

```
static T GetResponse<T>(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        error =  e.InnerException.ToString();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Generics:

```
static T GetMembers<T>(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error = e.InnerException.ToString();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a good candidate for generics. Perhaps..?

```
static E GetPiece< E >(HttpWebRequest request)    {
{
   ...  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MemberResponse membResp = (MemberResponse )StaticClassName.SerializeIt(request);

static Object SerializeIt(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MemberResponse));
            return (Object)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = e.InnerException.ToString();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's going to use typeof(MemberResponse) even when fetching an AttendeeResponse...

Answer (score -1):

You can eliminate duplicate code by delegates.
for example: 
if I have to finish two task against database :

```
 OleDbCommand oci = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
 oci.Connection.Open();
 oci.CommandText = "delete * from firstTable";
 oci.ExecuteNonQuery();
 oci.Connection.Close();

 OleDbCommand ocn = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
 ocn.Connection.Open();
 ocn.CommandText = "select count(*) from secondTable";
 int affected = convert.ToInt32(ocn.ExecuteScalar();
 ocn.Connection.Close();
```

as you can see we have duplicated code here. So I need to refactor my code like this:

```
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = null;
int count = -1;
OleDbWork(secondConnectionString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   secondTable",
out myAccessCommand,
() =>
{
     count = Convert.ToInt32(myAccessCommand.ExecuteScalar());

});

OleDbWork(firstConnectionString, "delete * from firstTable",
out myAccessCommand,
() =>
{
    myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and my OleDbWork method will look like this:

```
internal bool OleDbWork(string connString, string command,
out OleDbCommand myAccessCommand, Action action)
    {
        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;
        myAccessCommand = null;
        try
        {
            myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database!");

            return false;
        }

        try
        {

            myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(command, myAccessConn);

            myAccessConn.Open();

            action();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot retrieve data from database. \n{0}",
            ex.Message);

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            myAccessConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: This isn't going to be particularly relevant for the case described in this question.